# why is Makefile not executing alias statement

Tags: makefile

I am working on a class project that requires a makefile and needs to parse input below as an example
make
myapp arg1 arg2 arg3 arg4....

So I create a myapp.py

```
import sys
program_name = sys.argv[0]
arguments = sys.argv[1:]
count = len(arguments)
for x in sys.argv:
    print("Argument: ", x)
```

I create a Makefile

```
all:
    alias testapp="python3 myapp.py"
```

Doing this it should allow me to write 
$ testapp arg1 arg2 arg3... 
If I manually input the alias statement into the terminal it works correctly, but when run in a Makefile,
it doesn't work for me. Any ideas on a workaround for this?  thank you in advance

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is not specific to `make`.

Aliases are only supported in interactive shells by default.

Also, any code run in a subprocess (i.e. any command you run which is not a shell builtin) will be unable to change anything in the parent process (aliases, variables, etc). So you can't change the behavior of your current shell with `make`, or a script, or any other external command (except if you cause the shell to cooperate, for example by using a shell builtin which evaluates code printed by a subprocess - `eval` and `source` are two common ways to make the shell cooperate).

A simple way to accomplish what you want is to make sure `myapp.py` has a valid shebang as its very first line

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3
```

then make the file executable;

```
chmod +x myapp.py
```

then create a symlink to it with the name you want to use in a directory which exists on your `PATH`. Assuming `$HOME/bin` already exists and is already on your `PATH`, simply

```
ln -s $(pwd)/myapp.py $HOME/bin/testapp
```

in the directory where you have `myapp.py`.

Aliases have some drawbacks; maybe prefer shell functions where you could have used an alias.